# shutdown() wakes up select() but errno remains 0, no EBADF

Tags: linux, sockets

I am trying to debug a problem on linux that sometimes my TCP server blocks on a socket forever, though the socket is already gone. I wrote test code to understand the behavior of close(), shutdown(), select() and recv().

I have 2 threads - thread 1 blocks on a socket using select(), and thread 2 calls shutdown(SHUT_RDWR) on the same socket. When shutdown() is called from thread 2, thread 1 wakes up, select() returns 1 but errno reads 0. Also, after select() returns 1, recv() is called and it returns 0, again errno reads 0.

If I change the thread 2 implementation to use close() instead of shutdown(), select() never wakes up.

If I change the thread 2 implementation to call shutdown() followed by close(), select() returns 1 (errno remains 0) and then recv() returns -1 and errno reads EBADF.

My questions:

1. When close() is called, should select() not wake up? I looked up the close() man page, but could not ascertain what should happen.
2. When shutdown(SHUT_RDWR) is called, should select() return normally like what I see? Or should it return 1 and set errno to EBADF? If I look at the select() man page, it says errno is set to EBADF if one or more file descriptor sets specified a file descriptor that is not a valid open file descriptor. So looks like shutdown() only sends TCP FIN to the remote side but does not actually close the socket fd?
3. If I call shutdown() followed by close(), it seems to help. How is this different from calling close() alone?

Note: I understand that blocking on the socket in one thread and closing the same socket from another thread is not a good design, but I am dealing with a legacy codebase, so I can't change this design. I can only tweak it to call shutdown() and then close() as it seems to work, but I want to make sure I get the fundamental understanding right.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the test code:

Thread 1:

```
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "net/if.h"
#include "linux/sockios.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "strings.h"
#include "pthread.h"
#include "errno.h"

void* f1(void* p)
{
    int f1_ret, bytes, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in f1so1_addr;
    fd_set read_f1, error_fds;
    char f1buf[20];
    struct sockaddr clientInfo;
    socklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    f1so1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("f1: open fd's - f1fd1 = %d, f1so1 = %d\n", f1fd1, f1so1);
    f1so1_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    f1so1_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    //ret = inet_aton("10.20.30.100", &(f1so1_addr.sin_addr));
    f1so1_addr.sin_port = htons(7777);
    ret = bind(f1so1, (const struct sockaddr*) &f1so1_addr, sizeof(f1so1_addr));
    printf("f1: bind returned %x, errno = %x\n", ret, errno);
    listen(f1so1, 5);
    printf("f1- listening on f1so1, blocking on accept\n");
    f1so2 = accept(f1so1, &clientInfo, &clientAddrLen);
    printf("f1- accept returned %x, errno = %x\n", f1so2, errno);
    if(errno)
    {
            printf("f1: accept failed, return...\n");
            return;

    }

    FD_ZERO(&read_f1);
    FD_SET(f1so2, &read_f1);
    FD_ZERO(&error_fds);
    FD_SET(f1so2, &error_fds);


    printf("f1: start loop\n");


    while (1)
    {
            printf("f1: call select _read and error__ - cBLOCKING\n");
            errno = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&read_f1);
    FD_SET(f1so2, &read_f1);
    FD_ZERO(&error_fds);
    FD_SET(f1so2, &error_fds);

            f1_ret = select(f1so2+1, &read_f1, 0, &error_fds, 0);
            printf("f1: select returned = %x, errno = %x\n", f1_ret, errno);
            if (errno)
            {
                    printf("f1: select failed...\n");
            }
            else if (f1_ret)
            {
                            if (FD_ISSET(f1so2,&error_fds))
                            {
                                    printf("f1: error on socket %x\n",f1so2);
                            }
                            if (FD_ISSET(f1so2,&read_f1))
                            {
                                    sleep(1);
                                    bytes = recv(f1so2, f1buf, 20, 0);
                                    printf("f1: errno after recv = %x\n", errno);
                                    if (errno)
                                    {
                                            printf("!!!recv failed!!!\n");
                                            return;
                                    }
                                    printf("f1: read from socket %x, bytes = %x, data = %s\n",f1so2, bytes, f1buf);
                            }
            }
    }
    printf("f1: exiting\n");
}
```

Thread 2:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "pthread.h"
#include "linux/socket.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "net/if.h"
#include "linux/sockios.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "errno.h"
#include "strings.h"

extern int f1so2;

void f2()
{
    int f2_ret, i, choice;
    struct sockaddr_in f2so2_addr;
    fd_set read_f2;
    char f2buf[20];
    struct sigaction f2_act;

    while (1)
    {
            printf("f2: 1: close socket, 2: shutdown socket, 2: exit f2\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                    f2_ret = close(f1so2);
                    printf("f2: close on socket %x returned %x, errno = %x\n", f1so2, f2_ret, errno);
            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                    f2_ret = shutdown(f1so2, SHUT_RDWR);
                    printf("f2: shutdown on socket %x returned %x, errno = %x\n", f1so2, f2_ret, errno);
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                    continue;
            }
    }
    printf("f2: exiting\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour described is perfectly normal and should be expected. Shutdown then close, but prefer closing after select returns, and do not rely on EBADF (the fd can be reused and you will end up reading from an unrelated socket).

Comment: OK, thanks for that. But after shutdown(), select() returns normally, so how do I find out what actually happened? The fact that subsequent recv() returns -1 and sets EBADF is something that gives a clue but if you say this is unreliable, then what's the better way?

Comment: `recv` returning 0 bytes is the indication of the connection being shut down, like the EOF condition for any old file. It happens when the other side closes the connection too.

Comment: Ok, so when thread 2 calls shutdown(), thread 1 will wake up, select() will return 1 (errno set to 0) and recv() will return 0 (again errno set to 0). Once this is detected, I should call close()? my problem is, thread 2 is supposed to clean up the socket, so calling shutdown() and close() from thread 2 is desirable. Any chance it could be done? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that's the situation more or less. why can't thread2 clean up all the resources (free buffers etc) and thread1 just call the actual `close()` function? Or perhaps thread1 sending thread2 some message about sockets it may close?

Comment: OK, sounds good. BTW, another strange observation - when thread 2 calls shutdown(), select() in thread 1 wakes up and the loop runs infinitely, i.e. select() returns 1, followed by recv() which returns 0 and this goes on. Once socket is shutdown, shouldn't select() unblock only once? Why does select() persistently think that there is data available on that socket fd???

Comment: I think it's the system's way to tell you "close the socket and remove it from the FDSET ASAP, there will be no more data coming", but I'm really not sure.