# how to wakeup select() within timeout from another thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp

According to the "man select" information:

```
     "On  success,  select() and pselect() return the number of file descrip‐
   tors contained in the three returned  descriptor  sets which may be zero 
   if the timeout expires  before  anything  interesting happens.  On error, 
   -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately; the sets and timeout become
   undefined, so do not  rely  on  their  contents after an error."
```

Select will wakup because of:

```
       1)read/write availability       
       2)select error                 
       3)descriptoris closed.
```

However, how can we wake up the select() from another thread if there is no data available and the select is still within timeout?

**[update]**
Pseudo Code

```
          // Thread blocks on Select
          void *SocketReadThread(void *param){
               ...
               while(!(ReadThread*)param->ExitThread()) {
                   struct timeval timeout;
                   timeout.tv_sec = 60; //one minute
                   timeout.tv_usec = 0;

                   fd_set rds;
                   FD_ZERO(&rds);
                   FD_SET(sockfd, &rds)'

                   //actually, the first parameter of select() is 
                    //ignored on windows, though on linux this parameter
                   //should be (maximum socket value + 1)
                   int ret = select(sockfd + 1, &rds, NULL, NULL, &timeout );
                   //handle the result
                   //might break from here

               }
               return NULL;
          }

          //main Thread
          int main(){
                //create the SocketReadThread
                ReaderThread* rthread = new ReaderThread;
                pthread_create(&pthreadid, NULL, SocketReaderThread, 
                          NULL, (void*)rthread);

                 // do lots of things here
                 ............................

                //now main thread wants to exit SocketReaderThread
                //it sets the internal state of ReadThread as true
                rthread->SetExitFlag(true);
                //but how to wake up select ??????????????????
                //if SocketReaderThread currently blocks on select
          }
```

**[UPDATE]**
1) @trojanfoe provides a method to achieve this, his method writes socket data (maybe dirty data or exit message data) to wakeup select. I am going to have a test and update the result there.
2) Another thing to mention, closing a socket doesn't guarantee to wake up select function call, please see **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965053/shutdown-wakes-up-select-but-errno-remains-0-no-ebadf)**.

**[UPDATE2]**
After doing many tests, here are some facts about waking up select:
1) If the socket watched by select is closed **by another application**, then select() calling
will wakeup immediately. Hereafter, reading from or writing to the socket will get return value of 0 with an errno = 0
2) If the socket watched by select is closed by **another thread of the same application**,
then select() won't wake up until timeout if there is no data to read or write. After select timeouts, making read/write operation results in an error with errno = EBADF 
(because the socket has been closed by another thread during timeout period)

Comment: Writing to a closed connection will not return zero. Only reading does that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use an event object based on `pipe()`:

IoEvent.h:

```
#pragma once

class IoEvent {
protected:
    int m_pipe[2];
    bool m_ownsFDs;

public:
    IoEvent();              // Creates a user event
    IoEvent(int fd);        // Create a file event

    IoEvent(const IoEvent &other);

    virtual ~IoEvent();

    /**
     * Set the event to signalled state.
     */
    void set();

    /**
     * Reset the event from signalled state.
     */
    void reset();

    inline int fd() const {
        return m_pipe[0];
    }
};
```

IoEvent.cpp:

```
#include "IoEvent.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>

using namespace std;

IoEvent::IoEvent() : 
    m_ownsFDs(true) {
    if (pipe(m_pipe) < 0)
        throw MyException("Failed to create pipe: %s (%d)", strerror(errno), errno);

    if (fcntl(m_pipe[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
        throw MyException("Failed to set pipe non-blocking mode: %s (%d)", strerror(errno), errno);
}

IoEvent::IoEvent(int fd) : 
    m_ownsFDs(false) {
    m_pipe[0] = fd;
    m_pipe[1] = -1;
}

IoEvent::IoEvent(const IoEvent &other) {
    m_pipe[0] = other.m_pipe[0];
    m_pipe[1] = other.m_pipe[1];
    m_ownsFDs = false;
}

IoEvent::~IoEvent() {
    if (m_pipe[0] >= 0) {
        if (m_ownsFDs)
            close(m_pipe[0]);

        m_pipe[0] = -1;
    }

    if (m_pipe[1] >= 0) {
        if (m_ownsFDs)
            close(m_pipe[1]);

        m_pipe[1] = -1;
    }
}

void IoEvent::set() {
    if (m_ownsFDs)
        write(m_pipe[1], "x", 1);
}

void IoEvent::reset() {
    if (m_ownsFDs) {
        uint8_t buf;

        while (read(m_pipe[0], &buf, 1) == 1)
            ;
    }
}
```

You could ditch the `m_ownsFDs` member; I'm not even sure I use that any more.

Comment: You might want to make it more explicit that the reason this works is because you have the select() call in the other thread watching m_pipe[0] so that it wakes up when it is ready-for-read...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Agreed; I was waiting for some feedback from the OP, but he seems disinterested.

Comment: @trojanfoe I was reading your code thinking how it works, only to find that I don't understand why this can wakeup select until I saw comments from Jeremy Friesner :_) So your method will write socket data to wake up select, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  It's a cheap imitation of a Windows Event object when used with `WaitForMultipleObjects()`.  I typically use it for a quit event so if I'm in a `poll()` I also listen to this *quit event* and if I want the loop to quit I "set" the event.