# How to wakeup Select call without timeout period from another thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, rtos

I am searching solution to wake-up select call in c++, As per application requirement i cant set timeout because of multiple thread using select system call.

Please see below scenario.

i want to wakeup select system call waiting on other thread. I tried to write data on the thread from main thread but still it is not able to wakeup it.

I want to close thread and socket if there is empty data on this thread.

It is wakes up select call if socket connection is close from other process, but not working with thread.

Does any one have idea regarding this

Comment: There is no such thing as empty data in TCP. There are empty datagrams in UDP but it doesn't seem likely that's what you're talking about. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You can use self pipe trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/384397/2807083

Comment: You can also interrupt it with a `signal(3)`.

Comment: @EJP I am working on realtime application, whenever there is new thread, it is holding kernal resorves, I want to close all thread when destruction process for the application is going on, so that it will release all resources.

Comment: All you have to do is close the socket. I don't see 'realtime' in your question.

Comment: @arrowd Thanks for you suggestion, I am trying to write signal(3) handler, but I am not clear how it will help to wakeup select. I am new to signal handling programming

Comment: @EJP I have close the socket but still is not able to wake up socket, is anything more i need to add in it.

Comment: @arrowd thanks for your suggestion, signal(3) interrupt is useful in case of pselect, it will not wakeup select system call. For pselect we have write signal handle. I may case shutdown() working good :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all for valuable suggestion, I am able to resolve the issue with [shutdown()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) call on socket FD using reference answer present on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965053/shutdown-wakes-up-select-but-errno-remains-0-no-ebadf?lq=1#comment24505109_16965053), it will pass wakeup signal to select, which is waiting for action. We should close socket only after select call otherwise select will not able to get wake up signal.

Answer (score 3):

On a recent Linux you can use `eventfd`, on everything in general - a pipe, usage - register one side of the pipe in selector for readability along with actual socket(s), to wake up a selector - just write one byte to the other end of the pipe. Alternatively (if your libc has it) you can use `pselect` with a sigmask to catch the `ALRM` signal and raise that signal whenever you need to wake the selector up. Be very careful with using signals approach in a multithreaded application (as "I would not use"), as if not done right a signal may be delivered to a random thread.